# Get value from cache if it exists, else from DB, but don't write back to cache

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis

I have a use case, wherein, if a value exists in the cache, I'll retrieve from it, else, I'll query the DB, and provide the response, but don't want the result to be cached.

I went through different annotations - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial, but could not find anyone sufficing the use case.

Very simply, I want to do the following:

```
if value exists in cache
  return value
else
  return valueFromDB()
```

Since this code is for production services, I want to use annotations, and keep customization as minimum as possible.

Can someone guide me of a useful annotation for the case?

Comment: And how do you plan to "populate" cache? Assuming it initially empty...nothing writes ("back") ...it will always be `else`

Comment: So, the above operation is for a particular job.

Comment: You can assume, there are multiple jobs in the service, which are updating the cache.

Comment: That makes more sense! :)

Comment: Can you elaborate more, on how can I specify a condition, if the value exists in the cache? For this get/isExist part, is there some annotation available?

Comment: Oh, you mean, unless = "true" will not cache anything. I hope it doesn't evict out already existing entries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, starting with [gs-spring-caching/complete](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-caching/tree/main/complete), this:

```java
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "books", unless = "true") // !!!
public Book getSpecial(String isbn) { // ... same as sample
}
```

..gives us desired behavior:

- "books" cache is *always* issued,
- *never* written back,
- and "evicts" nothing.

---

Adjusting:

- `BookRepository` (interface)
- With a modified test (`AppRunner`):

  ```
  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.info(".... Fetching books");
        // populates cache with 1 book:
        logger.info("isbn-1234 -->" + bookRepository.getByIsbn("isbn-1234"));
        // always issues, never writes back to - cache:
        logger.info("isbn-1234 -->" + bookRepository.getSpecial("isbn-1234"));
        logger.info("isbn-4567 -->" + bookRepository.getSpecial("isbn-4567"));
        logger.info("isbn-1234 -->" + bookRepository.getSpecial("isbn-1234"));
        logger.info("isbn-4567 -->" + bookRepository.getSpecial("isbn-4567"));
        logger.info("isbn-1234 -->" + bookRepository.getSpecial("isbn-1234"));
        logger.info("isbn-1234 -->" + bookRepository.getSpecial("isbn-1234"));
  }
  ```
- add logging to "slow service"

..we can verify:

```bash
2022-10-07 14:04:24.917  INFO 7...Runner: .... Fetching books
2022-10-07 14:04:24.933  INFO 7...itory:  not from cache!
2022-10-07 14:04:27.934  INFO 7...Runner: isbn-1234 -->Book{isbn='isbn-1234', title='Some book'}
2022-10-07 14:04:27.937  INFO 7...Runner: isbn-1234 -->Book{isbn='isbn-1234', title='Some book'}
2022-10-07 14:04:27.939  INFO 7...itory:  not from cache!
2022-10-07 14:04:31.042  INFO 7...Runner: isbn-4567 -->Book{isbn='isbn-4567', title='Some book'}
2022-10-07 14:04:31.044  INFO 7...Runner: isbn-1234 -->Book{isbn='isbn-1234', title='Some book'}
2022-10-07 14:04:31.045  INFO 7...itory:  not from cache!
2022-10-07 14:04:34.066  INFO 7...Runner: isbn-4567 -->Book{isbn='isbn-4567', title='Some book'}
2022-10-07 14:04:34.067  INFO 7...Runner: isbn-1234 -->Book{isbn='isbn-1234', title='Some book'}
2022-10-07 14:04:34.068  INFO 7...Runner: isbn-1234 -->Book{isbn='isbn-1234', title='Some book'}
```

---

`condition="false"` gives us "no cache" behavior (so makes no sense on that annotation).

[@Cacheable-javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. Will check the behavior in my service as well.